# Populate data string in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that can have different number of text fields (holding translation value). Their names are for example: "textfield_eng", "textfield_ger", "textfield_dut".

In my ajax request I want these fields submitted of course, but I can't figure out how to populate these field names and their values in to the data string.

This is what the data call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: $("#optionForm").attr("action"),
   dataType: "xml",
   cache: false,
   data: { formname: $("#optionForm input[name='formname']").val(), 
    submit: $("#optionForm input[name='submit']").val()
    }, 
   success: function(xml){
                                bladibla....
```

And this is how I would like it to be:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: $("#optionForm").attr("action"),
   dataType: "xml",
   cache: false,
   data: { formname: $("#optionForm input[name='formname']").val(), 
    submit: $("#optionForm input[name='submit']").val(),
textfield_eng : "english",
textfield_ger : "german",
textfield_dut : "dutch"
    }, 
   success: function(xml){
                               bladiblla...
```

What is the best way to do this?

```
<input id="sOption_dut" name="sOption_dut" class="form_textfield" type="text" value="" />
<input id="sOption_eng" name="sOption_eng" class="form_textfield" type="text" value="" />
<input id="sOption_ger" name="sOption_ger" class="form_textfield" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: oh oops sorry. will do rightaway.

Comment: ok, much better now. Keep rewarding users who make an effort to provide a good and helpfull answer.

Comment: yes sir! Hopefully i can help some others on some other subjects too. but jquery is quite new to me.

Comment: remove comma `,` after `"dutch"` and put a comma `,` behind `val()`

Comment: thanks. a typo. but that is not the case. What i want to reach is that in site A (that runs languages "eng" and "dut") in need the script to generate the "textfield_eng" field too.
so the script needs to generate: textfield_eng: thevalue

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)? Makes submitting forms via ajax much easier.

Comment: just quickly. but dug into it a little deeper now and saw that you can submit data to a ajax request as an array as well [{'name': 'value'}, {'name':'value'}] and that certainly can help.
it does somehow walk through the form and creates this array so the answer must be somewhere there.

Comment: It also handles some of the anomalies that happen between browsers for you.  Makes live so much happier.

Answer (score 2):

Well figured it out all by myself. Checked in the jquery documentation and noticed that you could also submit the data string as an array (as mentioned as a comment above). That got me thinking in the right way.

This is how to do it:

```
    var aData = [];
    $("input", $("#myForm")).each(function(){
        aData.push({name: $(this).attr("name"), value: $(this).val()});
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        data: aData, 
        success: function(xml){
                           blablabla...
```

so, loop through the forms input fields (i only have textfields but if you have radios or selects, you need to change this a bit, look elsewhere on this site for tips on how to loop through a field) and then build the array. The only thing you have to do then is to push it in the ajax request.

it was after all that simple...

Comment: ok ... i had missed completely what the problem was.. sorry about that.. Take a look at `serializeArray()` of jQuery as it is what you want.. use it like `data: $('#myForm').serializeArray()`

Comment: Hi again. I tried that again and now i remember why this didn't work for me. serializeArray() doesn't serialize hidden fields and submit fields. that does work with the above lines.

Answer (score 0):

***update***
the way to create new text boxes with jquery would be

```
$('<input />').attr({
                     id: 'sOption_dut',
                     name: 'sOption_dut',
                     class: 'form_textfield' ,
                     type: 'text',
                     value: ''
                    }).appendTo('form_or_otherwise_selector_here');
```

The above shows how to create an input field with the specified attributes and then append it to some other element (usually a form).

Keep in mind that that code above should be executed either at page load, or when you decide to show the form to the end-user.. It should not be placed in the ajax call code as that would mean that it will get generated at the time of the submission, not giving the end-user the chance to fill in data.. (unless that is the intended effect..)

> change the
>   **form_or_otherwise_selector_here** to
>   tell it where to place the input box

---

<strike>You have a typo in your code</strike>

```
data: { formname: $("#optionForm input[name='formname']").val(), 
                submit: $("#optionForm input[name='submit']").val()
textfield_eng : "english",
textfield_ger : "german",
textfield_dut : "dutch",
                }
```

you need to remove the last comma (after the dutch text), and add one after the submit value ..
so it should be

```
data: { formname: $("#optionForm input[name='formname']").val(), 
                submit: $("#optionForm input[name='submit']").val(),
textfield_eng : "english",
textfield_ger : "german",
textfield_dut : "dutch"
                }
```

Comment: @Natrium, oups sorry.. did not see that .. So you want the user to be presented with these textboxes so he can fill in the data ?

Comment: Yes. the form would look something like this.
<input  id="sOption_dut" name="sOption_dut" class="form_textfield" type="text" value="" />
<input  id="sOption_eng" name="sOption_eng" class="form_textfield" type="text" value="" />
<input  id="sOption_ger" name="sOption_ger" class="form_textfield" type="text" value="" />

Comment: Gaby, the javascript wasn't meant to create the form, just to get the values from the form into the ajax request.